# High level / Abstract Canbus Interface in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hardware, can-bus

I am working with canbus in python (Pcan basic api) and would like to make it easier to use.

Via the bus a lot of devices/modules are connected. They are all allowed to send data, if a collison would happen the lowest ID will win.

The data Is organized in frames with ID, SubID, hexvalues

To illustrate the problem I am trying to adress, imagine the amplitude of a signal.

To read the value a frame is send to

- QuestionID QuestionSUBID QuestionData

If there is no message with higher priority(=lowerID) the answer is written to the bus:

- AnswerID AnswerSubID AnswerData

Since any module/device is allowed to write to the bus, you don't know in advance which answer you will get next. Setting a value morks the same way, just with different IDs. So for the above example the amplitude would have:

1. 4 IDs and SubIds Associated with read/write question/answer
2. Additionally the lenght of the data has (0-8) has to be specified /stored.
3. Since the data is all hex values a parser has to be specified to obtain the human readable value (e.g  Voltage in decimal representation)

To store this information I use nested dicts:

```
parameters = {'Parameter_1': {'Read': {'question_ID': ID, 
                                       'question_SUBID': SubID,
                                       'question_Data': hex_value_list,
                                       'answer_ID': ...,
                                       'answer_subID': ..., 
                                       'answer_parser': function},
                               'Write': {'ID': ...,
                                         'SubID': ...,
                                         'parser' ..., 
                                         'answer_ID': ...,
                                         'answer_subID': ...}},
               'Parameter_2': ... }}
```

There are a lot of tools to show which value was set when, but for hardware control, the order in which paremeters are read are not relevant as long as they are up to date. Thus one part of  a possible solution would be storing the whole traffic in a dict of dicts:

```
busdata = {'firstID' : {'first_subID': {'data': data, 
                                        'timestamp': timestamp},
                      'second_subID': {'data': data, 
                                        'timestamp': timestamp},

                      }, 
            secondID': ...}
```

Due to the nature of the bus, I get a lot of answers other devices asked  - the bus is quite full - these should not be dismissed since they might be the values I need next and there is no need to create additional traffic - I might use the timestamp with an expiry date, but I didn't think a lot about that so far.

This works, but is horrible to work with. In general I guess I will have about 300 parameters. The final goal is to controll the devices via a (pyqt) Gui, read some values like serial numbers but as well run measurement tasks.

So the big question is how to define a better datastructure that is easily accesible and understandable? I am looking forward to any suggestion on a clean design.

The main goal would be something like rid of the whole message based aproach.

**EDIT:** My goal is to get rid of the whole CAN specific message based aproach:

I assume I will need one thread for the communication, it should:

1. Read the buffer and update my variables
2. Send requests (messages) to obtain other values/variables
3. Send some values periodically

So from the gui I would like to be abled to:

1. get parameter by name --> send a string with parameter name
2. set parameter signal --> str(name), value(as displayedin the gui)
3. get values periodically --> name, interval, duration(10s or infinite)

The thread would have to:

1. Log all data on the bus for internal storage
2. Process requests by generating messages from name, value and read until result is obtained
3. Send periodical signals

I would like to have this design idependant of the actual hardware:

- The solution I thought of, is the above *parameters_dict*

For internal storage I thought about the *bus_data_dict*

**Still I am not sure how to**:

1. Pass data from the bus thread to the gui (all values vs. new/requested value)
2. How to implement it with signals and slots in pyqt
3. Store data internally (dict of dicts or some new better idea)
4. If this design is a good choice

Comment: make a class that abstracts this out ... canbus is based entirely on message packets so I dont think you can eliminate it ... but you can certainly abstract it ...

Comment: Yes, of course. Maybe i did state that clearly enough. The question is how to implement this. I thought about properties with proper getters and setters - still I would need an internal representation of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [python-can](https://bitbucket.org/hardbyte/python-can/) library will get you the networking thread - giving you a buffered queue of incoming messages. The library supports the PCAN interface among others.

Then you would create a middle-ware layer that converts and routes these `can.Message` types into pyqt signals. Think of this as a one to many source of events/signals.

I'd use another controller to be in charge of sending messages to the bus. It could have tasks like requesting periodic measurements from the bus, as well as on demand requests driven by the gui.

Regarding storing the data internally, it really depends on your programming style and the complexity. I have seen projects where each CAN message would have its own class.

Finally, queues are your friend!

Comment: Thanks. I took a quite similar route,  still trying to abstract it to mvc pattern.  Python-can only works with, same as the peak systems example.  I fixed their code by converting Unicode to byte strings.

Comment: What do you mean by "Python-can only works with"? In any system you will have to ensure you send bytes to the bus.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Hardbyte on the use of [python-can](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-can/).  It's excellent.

As far as messaging between app layers, I've had a lot of luck with [Zero MQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python) -- you can set up your modules as event based, from the canbus message event all the way through to updating a UI or whatever.

For data storage / persistence, I'm dropping messages into SQLite, and in parallel (using [ZMQ Pub/Sub](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) pattern) passing the data to an IoT hub (via [MQTT](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySimpleCanBus:
      def parse_message(self,raw_message):
          return MyMessageClass._create(*struct.unpack(FRAME_FORMAT,msg))
      def recieve_message(self,filter_data):
          #code to recieve and parse a message(filtered by id)
          raw = canbus.recv(FRAME_SIZE)
          return self.parse_message(raw)
      def send_message(msg_data):
          # code to make sure the message can be sent and send the message
          return self.recieve_message()

class MySpecificCanBus(MySimpleCanBus):
    def get_measurement_reading():
         msg_data = {} #code to request a measurement
         return self.send_message(msg_data)
    def get_device_id():
         msg_data = {} # code to get device_id
         return self.send_message(msg_data)
```

I probably dont understand your question properly ... maybe you could update it with additional details